# Manhwa where the main character is in a game world and gets into a fight with a bigger group, because of a "fishing spot"

Tags: story-identification, manga, virtual-worlds

The fishing spot was some kind of event and everyone fought over it as soon as they understood its value. He could get different stuff from there if he caught a golden fish. Only a few attempts per day?

He visits a few of them until he gets "cornered" by two different groups that are mad because he stole those good spots. He fights them back because of the level difference.